# Pythons Webbrowser Module Will Never Open a Link in a new Window

Tags: python, google-chrome, firefox, python-webbrowser

I was trying to automate opening multiple user profiles given a list of names on a few different sites but i can not find a way to open a link in a new window meaning i can not sort the different sites i am opening into their own window collection.

here is my code:

```
import webbrowser


chrome_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
firefox_path="C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\Firefox.exe"
strURL = "http://www.python.org"


webbrowser.register('chrome', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path),1)
webbrowser.register('firefox', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path),1)

webbrowser.open(strURL, new=0)
webbrowser.open(strURL, new=1)
webbrowser.open(strURL, new=2)
webbrowser.get('chrome').open(strURL)
webbrowser.get('firefox').open(strURL)
webbrowser.get('chrome').open_new(strURL)
webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new(strURL)
```

no matter what value i put for new (0, 1, or 2), all that ever happens is it opens a new tab in the last window i clicked on. i have tried all of the other methods that i found in they python documentation for the webbrowser module and everyone online is just saying to use "new=1" or webbroswer.open_new() but neither of those work. and even when i point it at firefox it just goes to chrome.

P.S.

i found a small workaround that i am not totally satisfied with.

```
import webbrowser


chrome_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
chrome_path_NW = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s --new-window"
firefox_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\Firefox.exe"
strURL = "http://www.python.org"

controller = webbrowser.get(chrome_path)
controllerNW = webbrowser.get(chrome_path_NW)

controllerNW.open(strURL, new=0)
controller.open(strURL, new=1)
controller.open(strURL, new=2)
controller.open("www.youtube.com", new=2)
```

the important thing to look at would be the "chrome_path" variable. i have changed it so it will run as a command and accept arguments. i found some launch arguments for chromium, here, that seem to work from chrome too. "--new-window" will open a new window and i can then open more tabs in that window but this is a total workaround of pythons module that i am not confident won't break if i am trying to use chrome while running this script. if there is any feature where i could group links together to open in specific windows that would be much more useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a bit late but hopefully i can help someone in the future.
Basically you need to use the subprocess module to open up a new window before you load a new webpage

```
import subprocess
import time
import webbrowser

subprocess.Popen('open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --new', shell=True)
time.sleep(0.5) # this is to let the app open before you try to load a new page
webbrowser.open(url)
```